# Why my material is not showing on the render but in the preview of the right-side of the screen?

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine

i came back after a long christmas break of using blender and i just found this problem while following a tutorial. I made all the steps that are shown in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3wghbZ-Vh4 and i see that isn't the same.

A better example:
[image]

So, the question is, what's happening? what am i doing wrong?
Just in case, i unwrapped the ball and isn't looking the same as in the right side preview.

This is how it looks with everything included to look "Realistic or photorealistic" (I'm using the Poliigon materials), and there not much changes in the rendered image.

[image]

EDIT: i found that i made a miss-step and didn't unwrap correctly. Now i unwrapped it on sphere projection, but still it looks flat :/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need texture coordinates on your sphere. Either use generated coordinates or UV unwrap your Sphere.

Use the mapping node to transform your texture.

[image: box mapping blender]

[image: box mapping blender]

Comment: That will solve the "flatness" of the Normal map texture, the roughness of the gloss pbr material and the reflection of the reflection PBR material?

Comment: @J.J. I added a possible setup, unfortunately I can't share the textures. Use micropolygon displacement and a good set of textures with roughness, glossyness, color and displacement information.